# Edit markers's lat-lng in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Map DrawingManager to add Markers to map. After a marker is added, it also adds a column into the table below the map. This column has some information about the marker (title, description, lat, lng) and 2 links (Edit and Delete). You can see that on this photo.

[image]

User can click `delete` to remove a marker and `edit` to edit marker's information. I have done `delete` function but haven't done `edit` function. I have tried a few solutions but they weren't working. Does anyone have any solution to do this? Thanks in advance.

My source code:

```js
var $body = $('body'),
  markers = {},
  html = '<tr>' +
  '<td><input type="text"></td>' +
  '<td><input type="text"></td>' +
  '<td><input type="text" value="" class="marker-lat"><input type="text" value="" class="marker-lng"></td>' +
  '<td><a href="#" class="edit-marker">Edit</a><a href="#" class="delete-marker">Delete</a></td>' +
  '</tr>';

initMap();

function initMap() {
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-16.920334, 145.770859),
    zoom: 12,
  };

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingControl: false,
  });

  var map = new google.maps.Map($('.map')[0], myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'markercomplete', function(marker) {
    var pos = marker.getPosition(),
      obj = {
        lat: pos.lat(),
        lng: pos.lng()
      };

    $('.marker-table').find('tbody').append(html);
    $('.marker-table').find('.marker-lat:last').val(obj.lat);
    $('.marker-table').find('.marker-lng:last').val(obj.lng);

    markers[obj.lat + ':' + obj.lng] = marker;
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'polylinecomplete', function(line) {
    var paths = '';
    path = line.getPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
      paths += path.getAt(i) + ";";
    }
    $('.paths').val(paths);
  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);

  $body.on('click', '.add-marker', function() {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
  });

  $body.on('click', '.draw-line', function() {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE);
  });

  $body.on('click', '.delete-marker', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
      $tr = $this.closest('tr'),
      lng = $tr.find('.marker-lng').val(),
      lat = $tr.find('.marker-lat').val(),
      marker;

    e.preventDefault();

    markers[lat + ':' + lng].setMap(null);

    $tr.remove();
  });

  $body.on('click', '.edit-marker', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script><input type="button" value="Add Marker" class="add-marker">
<input type="button" value="Draw a line" class="draw-line">
<div class="map" style="width: 600px;  height: 200px;"></div>
<table class="marker-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" class="paths" name="paths">
```

Here is [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxx5osk8/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out a solution to do this.

Instead of using `markers[obj.lat + ':' + obj.lng] = marker;` to store markers, I use `markers[index] = marker;` (index is integer number).

Here is my change:

```
var index = 0;

google.maps.event.addDomListener( drawingManager, 'markercomplete', function( marker ) 
    {
        var pos = marker.getPosition();

        $( '.marker-table' ).find( 'tbody' ).append( html );
        $( '.marker-table' ).find( '.marker-lat:last' ).val( pos.lat() );
        $( '.marker-table' ).find( '.marker-lng:last' ).val( pos.lng() );
        $( '.marker-table' ).find( '.marker-index:last' ).val( index );         

        markers[index] = marker;
        index++;
    } );

    $body.on( 'click', '.edit-marker', function( e )
    {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var $this = $( this ),
            $tr = $this.closest( 'tr' ),
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($tr.find( '.marker-lat' ).val(), $tr.find( '.marker-lng' ).val());

        markers[$tr.find( '.marker-index' ).val()].setPosition(latlng);
    } );
```